# How can to show Interstitial ad after "X" no. of clicks in app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

I am using this code to show ads. How can I show ads when the user clicks on the content of my app after a specific period of clicks? Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);

    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });

}
public void displayInterstitial() {

    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Create sharedpreference in  launch screen and store an int with value 0 and at every click get value of that int and check it and if it's matches with 'X' clicks load and show interstatial ad or if it's not match increment in value.